# Java (eclipse): How to call a int or string from another class in same project?

Tags: java, eclipse, string, class

How can I use an int or string from another class in same project, for example, here we go with a class called `Estadisticas`:

```
public class Estadisticas {

    public void stats() {

        final String c1 = "Tu personaje";
        final int Nivel = 1;
        final int Salud = 50;
        final int Ataque = 2;
        final int Defensa = 1;

        final String c2 = "Primer monstruo - Rata rabiosa";
        final int SaludM1 = 2;
        final int AtaqueM1 = 1; 

    }
}
```

And I want to know how to call for example the String c1 to println like this:

```
public class Start extends Estadisticas {
    public static void main() {
        System.out.println(String c1);
    }

}
```

After reading some example codes and people with similar problem, I tried with `extends Estadisticas` with no luck, and I'm putting this code as I don't know how to call that string from another class in same project.

Thanks in advance!
Cristobal.

Comment: Variables declared inside of a method (in this case stats) are only visible for that method. Declare them as public in your class, then you can access them

Comment: I have the feeling you want to start to big... start with the beginning, don't try to make a game without knowing the language... a pretty good tutorial = http://www.learnjavaonline.org/

Comment: your c1 is method scoped variable, you can not access it in another class directly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to call a variable from another class, you have several options:

1) Declare the variable in the other class as static:

```
public class Estadisticas {

  public static String c1 = "Tu personaje";
  ...
}
```

So in the other class, you can just call the string like so:

```
public class Start extends Estadisticas {
  public static void main() {
    System.out.println(Estadisticas.c1);
  }
}
```

2) Have the stats method return the string:

```
public String stats() {

  final String c1 = "Tu personaje";
  final int Nivel = 1;
  final int Salud = 50;
  final int Ataque = 2;
  final int Defensa = 1;

  final String c2 = "Primer monstruo - Rata rabiosa";
  final int SaludM1 = 2;
  final int AtaqueM1 = 1; 

  return c1;
}
```

So you can do this:

```
public class Start extends Estadisticas {
  public static void main() {
    Estadisticas es = new Estadisticas();
    System.out.println(es.stats());
  }
}
```

3) Use an accessor method and instance variables:

```
public class Estadisticas {
  private String c1, c2;
  private int nivel, salud, ataque, defensa, saludM1, ataqueM1;

  public void stats() {
    c1 = "Tu personaje";
    nivel = 1;
    salud = 50;
    ataque = 2;
    defensa = 1;

    c2 = "Primer monstruo - Rata rabiosa";
    saludM1 = 2;
    ataqueM1 = 1; 
  }

  //accessor method
  public String getc1() {
    return c1;
  }
}
```

So in the other class you can use:

```
public class Start extends Estadisticas {
  public static void main() {
    Estadisticas es = new Estadisticas();
    System.out.println(es.getc1());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this :

```
public class Estadisticas {
    final String c1 = "Tu personaje";
    final int Nivel = 1;
    final int Salud = 50;
    final int Ataque = 2;
    final int Defensa = 1;

    final String c2 = "Primer monstruo - Rata rabiosa";
    final int SaludM1 = 2;
    final int AtaqueM1 = 1; 

    public void stats() {

    }
}

public class Start extends Estadisticas {
    public static void main() {
     Estadisticas  es = new Estadisticas (); // create instance here
        System.out.println(es.c1);  // print using the instance


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is public example. In java you need to use them as private for security.

```
public class Estadisticas {
                public String c1 = "Tu personaje";
                public int Nivel = 1;
    }
```

This is calling from another class.

```
    public class Start {
        public static void main() {

            Estadisticas.Nivel;
            Estadisticas.c1 ;
        }
  }
```

Comment: The fields aren't *static*.